# How to make inequality SARGable for my first_name column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
 select * from [sales].[customers] where first_name <> 'Debra'
```

I want to make my query SARGable as I have a NON CLUSTERED INDEX on the `first_name` :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already is sargable.

SQL Server can convert that into two range seeks on `> 'Debra'` and `< 'Debra'` if it deems it beneficial.

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers(
CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(10) INDEX ix_first_name, 
last_name VARCHAR(100)
)

SELECT first_name 
FROM #Customers
where first_name <> 'Debra'

DROP TABLE #Customers
```

[image]

Unless you have a **covering** index with leading column `first_name` this is unlikely to be beneficial though as likely only a small proportion of the table will be excluded and SQL Server won't use an index seek if it expects it needs to do a high proportion of lookups.

Comment: Why it is not using INDEX SEEK then ?

Comment: probably you don't have an index with leading column `first_name` that includes all columns in the table (for the `select *`). If you do `select first_name from [sales].[customers] where first_name <> 'Debra' ` then you should see a seek (if you have an index on first_name)

Answer (score 0):

Why the optimizer isn't using `INDEX SEEK` ?

Indexes with included columns provide the greatest benefit when covering the query. This means that the index includes all columns referenced by your query, as you can add columns with data types, number or size not allowed as index key columns.

Your query is already SARGable , you can modify your index as below :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index_cols] ON [sales].[customers]
(
    [first_name] 
)
INCLUDE (   [othercolumns], [..] ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Likely this wouldn't be worth the overhead though. Assuming that at most 1% of the population is called Debra the advantage of avoiding a scan and reading those 1% additional rows is fairly minimal and this basically duplicates the entire table

Comment: @MartinSmith so you say no need for the INCLUDE if we want an INDEX SEEK?

Comment: No - I'm saying the benefit of a seek that reads 99% of the rows is pretty minimal vs a scan reading 100% of the rows and maintaining this index comes at a cost that probably can't be justified by that minimal gain